# Releasing PlaceBufferResponse

Tags: android, kotlin, geolocation, google-play-services, google-places-api

I am using PlaceBufferResponse in code below, but compiler says **release is internal** and don't use it, then how shall I release it?

```
val placeResult = mGeoDataClient.getPlaceById(placeId)
            placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(object : OnCompleteListener<PlaceBufferResponse> {
                override fun onComplete(task: Task<PlaceBufferResponse>) {
                    val places = task.getResult();
                    val place = places.get(0)

                    isAutoCompleteLocation = true
                    latLng = place.latLng
                    assignToMap()

                    places.release()
                }

            })
```

Document says you should **release** :

> NOTE: The calling application must release() this object after it is
>   done with it to prevent a memory leak. Refer to the developer's guide
>   for more information about handling buffers.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/PlaceBufferResponse.html#release()

Comment: The code you are posting is just fine , I've tested your code and its working on my system properly without any compile time error or warning.

Comment: Yes, apparently it's a bug in Google Play Services V12, working fine on previous versions.